# Join using points in a table within ranges in another table in R

Tags: r, join

Let's say I have 2 tables:

df1:

```
start end
15    20
22    32
35    52
```

df2:

```
point 
12 
16
17    
21  
26   
31   
43
```

I want to join the two tables so that I have which points are between ranges:

```
start end  point
15    20   16
15    20   17
22    32   26
22    32   31
35    52   43
```

How do I do this in R? I know for joining 2 tables when 2 tables have start and end, I can use `foverlap`, but I don't know how to do this when one of the table only has one point.

Comment: With `data.table` non-equi join: `df2[df1, .(start, end, point = x.point), on = .(point >= start, point <= end), nomatch = 0L]`

Comment: With the `tidyverse`: `crossing(df1, df2) %>% 
  filter(point >= start, point <= end)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `fuzzy_join`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_inner_join(df1, df2, by = c('start' = 'point', 'end' = 'point'),
        match_fun = list(`<=`, `>=`))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  start   end point
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1    15    20    16
#2    15    20    17
#3    22    32    26
#4    22    32    31
#5    35    52    43
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(start = c(15L, 22L, 35L), end = c(20L, 32L, 52L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(point = c(12L, 16L, 17L, 21L, 26L, 31L, 43L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```